# ARPACK error -9999: Could not build an Arnoldi factorization

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to solve a generalized eigenvalue problem. For problem that I have in mind, I would like to use `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh`. I have written a MWE

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.linalg import eigh
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigsh, LinearOperator

n = 3
v = np.random.random(n)
A = np.diag(np.arange(n))
M = np.eye(n)

Aop = LinearOperator((n,n), matvec=lambda v: A@v)
Mop = LinearOperator((n,n), matvec=lambda v: M@v)

eig, vec = eigh(A, M)
print(eig)
print(vec)
eig, vec = eigsh(Aop, k=1, M=Mop, v0=v, which="LA")
```

The output when running the script

```
[0. 1. 2.]
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anian/Documents/comb-efficient/mps_python/eig/gevp.py", line 17, in <module>
    eig, vec = eigsh(Aop, k=1, M=Mop, v0=v, which="LA")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_eigen/arpack/arpack.py", line 1689, in eigsh
    params.iterate()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_eigen/arpack/arpack.py", line 571, in iterate
    raise ArpackError(self.info, infodict=self.iterate_infodict)
scipy.sparse.linalg._eigen.arpack.arpack.ArpackError: ARPACK error -9999: Could not build an Arnoldi factorization. IPARAM(5) returns the size of the current Arnoldi factorization. The user is advised to check that enough workspace and array storage has been allocated.
```

I am using Python 3.10.8 and Scipy 1.9.3. Any advice how to solve this? I know I can simply use `scipy.linalg.eigh`, but my actual problem requires the use of LinearOperator.
If I set `M=None` in the line of `eigsh`, the script runs fine.

**EDIT**

Interestingly, if I specify the `sigma` keyword, it seems to run:

```
eig, vec = eigsh(Aop, k=1, M=Mop, v0=v, which="LA", sigma=1.2)
```

It is a bit unsatisfactory, though, as it requires having a good guess of an eigenvalue.